# How to fix a “413 request entity too large” on digital ocean-django app

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn, digital-ocean

I recently deployed a django app to digital ocean using gunicorn and nginx, the app is working but while trying to upload files, it threw an error

> 413 request entity too large

I've tried some suggestions on this stackflow which state that there is need to add `client_max_body_size`  to `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`, when I did this, an error

> client_max_body_size directive not allowed in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

was thrown. I really do not know what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if client_max_body_size is properly declared as it may need additional configuration. Also, set the upload_max_filesize, post_max_size. [Check this article](https://www.keycdn.com/support/413-request-entity-too-large)

Comment: Thanks very much, following your comment and the article, I was able to solve the issue by putting **client_max_body_size in the http basic settings and not in server as that threw an error**. Thanks for the help

Comment: this saved my long hours of googling